# 英語が残っている：ヘルプの右メニュー

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

Code of Conduct：行動規範
Manifesto of Stack Overflow in Japanese：スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版のマニフェスト(※わざとであればその旨お伝えください)
以上の２つのリンク先は翻訳されています。

What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?：タグwikiに入れるべき内容とは何ですか？
この項目はリンク先も未訳となっています。

Comment: ありがとうございます！　前者のふたつは既知の問題で、ヘルプのタイトルはSE Teamでないと編集できないと聞いた覚えがあります。@aki さんに伺ってみます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

タイトルが以下の通り変更されました。

Code of Conduct：スタック・オーバーフローの行動規範　
Manifesto of Stack Overflow in Japanese：スタック・オーバーフローのマニフェスト

2019年1月7日追記：
What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?の和訳は以下で反映されております。
[タグwikiの抜粋(要約)にはどんな内容を記述すればいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts)